# DataGridTextColumn Header DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml

This may (hopefully) have a trivial or very simple answer.

Suppose I want customized headings for my `DataGrid`. I can use a `DataTemplate` as so:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}">
    <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="Header Text" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

However, if there are many columns it is less cumbersome to be able to use something like

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}">
    HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderTemplate}"
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

where `ColumnHeaderTemplate` is my custom `DataTemplate`. My question is how do I pass the "Header Text" to the `DataTemplate`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can do it by binding `TextBlock.Text` and you can do it either for all column headers in a `DataGrid` by changing `ContentTemplate` of header to be your custom `TextBlock` and then just set `Header` to text you want to display. It will also apply to automatically generated columns

```
<DataGrid ...>
   <DataGrid.Resources>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
         <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
               <DataTemplate>
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
               </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
         </Setter>
      </Style>
   </DataGrid.Resources>
   <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Header Text">
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

or can also do it per column just change `TextBlock.Text` in you header template to use binding, as above

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
```

and then you column could look like this:

```
<DataGridTextColumn 
    Binding="{Binding Name}" 
    HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderTemplate}"
    Header="Header Text"/>
```

Comment: This does not work for me unless I set MaxWidth of the column