# DataGrid for import with drop down column headers

Tags: c#, csv, mvvm, import

I'm creating an import utility for my system. Currently I'm pulling the template of the currently selected table and importing CSV's successfully only when their headers /column count directly match up.

What I'd like to do is have a generic or 'headerless' datagrid which had drop down selectors at the top of each column to select it's desired destination in the table.

Does anyone know the best way to go about this? Is it possible to have a generic datagrid to import CSV's into?

Comment: What you're trying to do has nothing to do with [generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/). You could certainly write [a DataGrid header template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26692234/datagridtextcolumn-header-datatemplate) with a combobox in it, and bind the combobox to something on the viewmodel that would rearrange the columns of the items in a collection. There's nothing particularly difficult there, but it'll be you writing the code.

Comment: yeah alright. that's the direction I was thinking of moving. thanks.

Comment: Use my CSVReader at following posting and set headers to false : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30129406/reading-data-from-csv-to-screen-output