# Complex header styled in WPF

Tags: wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

Is it possible to take something like this:

```
<DataGridTextColumn.Header>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label Content="BlahBlahBlah"/>
        <Expander x:Name="Blah_Filter"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataGridTextColumn.Header>
```

And make it a style so I don't have to type it out for every column. I would like to name the columns individually also, if that's possible. Per usual any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26692234/datagridtextcolumn-header-datatemplate

Comment: I think that was close. The column already has a Binding property so I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the header `ContentTemplate` with something like

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}"
           x:Key="ColumnHeaderTemplate">
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Label Content="{Binding}" />
                        <Expander />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Column1Content}"
                            HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderTemplate}"
                            Header="BlahBlahBlah1" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Column2Content}"
                            HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderTemplate}"
                            Header="BlahBlahBlah2" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

where `Column1Content` and `Column2Content` are the bindings to your cell datas and `BlahBlahBlah1` and `BlahBlahBlah1` are the header titles.

Comment: This worked perfectly, I just had to set the   <DataTemplate> as the key and remove the <Style> and <Setter> tags. Thank you!

Comment: @RMason: Glad it helped!

Comment: Just a tip, if you apply the same `DataGridColumnHeader` to all`DataGridTextColumn`, apply the style globally by removing the key on style `x:Key="ColumnHeaderTemplate" `and also remove the ` HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderTemplate}" ` in  each `DataGridTextColumn`. it will eleminate the need of applying the style for each `DataGridTextColumn`.